# "Good" Flay Score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-analysis

I'm working on a rails project and we're running [Flay](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flay.html) on it. Its got a score of ~1400 and I'm unsure what this really means. I know that 0 is ideal but I'm unsure what a good target would be and what a realistic upper-bound for a project should be. Is there any good documentation on the scoring process and what the end-result is?

Comment: Nope, I ment [Flay](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flay.htm), its from the same group that made Flog

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a simple solution to this dilemma, which applies not only to Flay, but pretty much all "badness" scores: set the upper-bound to whatever the current score is, and whenever it decreases, set it to the new value.

That way, you guarantee

1. that your goal is realistic (because it will *already* be fulfilled) and
2. that you only ever improve, or in the worst case stagnate, but you never get worse.

Comment: It seems that this value (and others like it) is only used as a comparative value over the lifetime of a project. A single value is useless, but the difference between the score at two different points in time will give insight into the progress of the project. Its a vector value, not a scalar.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a link regarding Flog's scoring process and how to refactor your project to reduce its score. *(I figure since Flay is similar to Flog the scoring process should be similar)*

[Scoring your Rail Application's Complexity](http://www.railsinside.com/tutorials/487-how-to-score-your-rails-apps-complexity-before-refactoring.html)

Here is another, albeit older link (2008) with a discussion on Flog's scoring system:

[Jake Scruggs - What's a good Flog Score?](http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/2008/08/whats-good-flog-score.html)

You can also take a look at [Caliper](http://devver.net/caliper), which is another Ruby metrics tool.

Hope these helped!

Comment: It looks like Caliper is shutting down as of April 30, 2011